# Was the sign U gunû actually pronounced "ugunu"?

Tags: cuneiform, sumerian, akkadian

In Sumero-Akkadian cuneiform, the Akkadian word *gunû* "colored, decorated" is used to describe signs hatched across with little diagonal strokes. For example, the sign GAŠAN "lady" () is the sign U "ten" () *gunû*.

Images, for those without cuneiform fonts:

[image: GAŠAN]
[image: U]

However, according to [the ePSD](http://psd.museum.upenn.edu/epsd/epsd/e6008.html), GAŠAN can actually be read as UGUNU₂—that is, actually pronounced as *ugunu*!

Was this really the case? Or did a sign name get misinterpreted somewhere along the line? I could imagine this sign arising as a pun—to write the word *ugunu*, write the word *u*, then make it *gunû* (decorated)—but I can also imagine a clerical error mistaking a sign description for a sign reading.

Comment: Good question. The ePSD entry for [ugunu \[DECORATION\]](http://psd.museum.upenn.edu/epsd/epsd/e6007.html) features a variety of phonetic spellings strongly suggesting that a Sumerian word _ugunu_ at least existed. However, I haven't yet managed to locate any attested usages of the GAŠAN / UGUNU₂ sign that clearly should be read in context as _ugunu_ (in either sense) rather than as _gašan_. If they exist, I suspect they're probably somewhere in some ancient word list.

Comment: Update: CAD (under _bēltu_) cites a lexical entry "u-gu-nu GAŠAN = _be-el-tum_ A II/4:221." AFAICT "A" here refers to the "lexical series á A = _nâqu_", of which I have so far been unable to locate a copy online. Still, it at least suggests a likely origin for this reading. Of course, whether the lexical entry accurately reflects a genuine Sumerian pronunciation is another matter entirely…